# allowing / parsing compressed or uncompressed pickles or json files?

Tags: python, json, compression, pickle

I'd like to write a method that takes a filename as input, then checks to see if the file is compressed or not (gzip, xz/LZMA, none) and then checks whether the contents of the file are a pickled python object or a JSON encoded dictionary.  The goal here is to provide users with some amount of flexibility in how they store/encode the data, which is ultimately just a bunch of strings...

What's the most sensible way of structuring this code?  Do I just `try` to open the file with each of the supported (de)compressors, or is there some better way to determine the file type and call the corresponding `open` method?

Similar question for the data inside... short of actually trying `json.load()` or `pickle.load()` and catching exceptions, is there some more elegant/efficient/maintainable way to do this?

I know I can bang together enough if-then-else or try-except logic to end up making it work, but I'm new enough to this that I'd like to at least solicit input on what might make the most sense.  I guess in some sense I'm asking whether the philosophy should be

- "probe something to figure out what the file actually is, then call the open/load based on that answer"

  - as opposed to ...
- "loop through, trying all the things you know how to handle and end up using the one that doesn't throw an exception"

Answer (score 1):

The first six bytes of an xz file are, in hex, `fd 37 7a 58 5a 00`. The first three bytes of a gz file are `1f 8b 08`.

A JSON stream must start with a `'{'` or `'['`. A pickle file must start with an opcode, [which *today* does not include](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Lib/pickletools.py) `'{'` or `'['`, or `'\xfd'` or `'\x1f'`.

So unless opcodes are added to the pickle format that overlaps with JSON or the compressed data signatures, and if you know your input must be one of those four, and decompressed data must be one of those two, then it looks like you can do what you want.

Note that decoding the pickle format effectively executes Python code, so it is not considered secure. It should not be used with an untrusted originator.

Scraped from the linked source, here are the Python 3.8.1 pickle opcodes:

```
'(', ')', '.', '0', '1', '2', 'B', 'C', 'F', 'G', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N',
'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'X', ']', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'g',
'h', 'i', 'j', 'l', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', '}', '\x80', '\x81',
'\x82', '\x83', '\x84', '\x85', '\x86', '\x87', '\x88', '\x89', '\x8a', '\x8b',
'\x8c', '\x8d', '\x8e', '\x8f', '\x90', '\x91', '\x92', '\x93', '\x94', '\x95',
'\x96', '\x97', '\x98'
```